# RCP Customize Perspective bar

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have to customize the perspective bar in an RCP application. In the extensions tab I have this hierarchy:

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
   <menuContribution locationURI="toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.trim.command1">
      <toolbar id="thevendor.horizontalBar1">
         <control
            class="thevendor.MyButton"
            id="thevendor.MyButton">
         </control>
         <control
            class="thevendor.AnotherContribution"
            id="thevendor.AnotherContribution">
         </control>
      </toolbar>
   </menuContribution>
</extension>
```

the problem is that RCP display the toolbar with `MyButton`, `AnotherContribution` and a perspective menu that I don't want. I try to set `IWorkbenchWindowConfigurer.setShowPerspectiveBar` to `false`, *but the whole toolbar disappears*.
How to hide only this perspective menu, showing only `MyButton` and `AnotherContribution`?

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you might have set up your toolbar incorrectly. I've tried something similar just the other day, and used the wrong extension hierarchy, so the toolbar didn't work at all...

To add a custom toolbar to your RCP, do the following:

- In your `plugin.xml`, go to the Extensions page. Right-click the extension `org.eclipse.ui.menus`, choose *New*, choose *menuContribution*.
- In the form, set the field `locationURI` to "toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar" (without the quotes).
- Right-click on the "menuContribution" you have just edited, choose *New*, choose *toolbar*.
- (Edit toolbar to suit your needs.)
- Right-click the new toolbar extension, choose *New*, choose *command*.
- Browse for the `commandId` you want to use.
- Then, in your `WorkbenchWindowAdvisor.preWindowOpen()` method, set the following:

  `configurer.setShowCoolBar(true);`

  `configurer.setShowPerspectiveBar(false);`

This should work. I hope :).